# Encode world matrix as 2 float4s?

Tags: matrix, skinning, palette

On one of the slides of their presentation ["Batch, Batch, Batch!"](http://ce.u-sys.org/Veranstaltungen/Interaktive%20Computergraphik%20%28Stamminger%29/papers/BatchBatchBatch.pdf) guys from NVidia suggest encoding animation matrices for pallet skinning into two float4s as:

> • axis/angle
>
> • translate/uniform scale

I wonder how can that be done (including decoding) and why do they say that this leads to:

> Video memory overhead: model replication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Encode world matrix as 2 float4s

2 float4 means 2 vectors, encoding these in two vectors is easy and is actually common.

This can easily be done:

- axis/angle -> axis ( x,y,z 3 floats  ), angle ( 1 float ).
- translate/uniform scale -> ( x,y,z 3 floats ), uniform scale ( 1 float ).

Now decoding this is as easy constructing a 4x4 matrix from scaling, rotation and translation.

Now my interpretation of

> Video memory overhead: model replication

If it caused video memory overhead, you can optimize it by using model replication, in other words use the same bone transforms for different models (instancing). Instead of submitting new transform for each new skeleton.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) does C# have a method that extracts these elements from a ready Matrix? 2) if I were multiplying a position matrix with the matrix I need compressed in the shader (input.position = mul(input.position, matrix);) how do I need to change my code? I can't understand how you construct a 4x4 matrix from these elements.

Comment: @cubrman C# is a language, you need to use an external matrix library. Regarding your second question I think you need to understand how matrices work before you can understand this. I suggest picking up matrix tutorial online. like this one http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vectorindex.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will pick your answer as the right one because it best fits the question.

Answer (score 2):

As concept3d said, a pair of float4s means 8 components total (so half the size of a 16-component matrix), and you can just fit a rotation, translation, and uniform scale value into 8 components.  (Although I would use a quaternion rather than axis-angle - that way no trig functions need to be used in the vertex shader to apply the rotation.)

As for the "Video memory overhead: model replication" comment, this is my best guess:

The context of the talk is trying to reduce the number of batches (draw calls) by combining multiple models together in a batch.  You would ordinarily have to create a new batch every time you changed the world matrix, so the speaker envisions doing this with bones instead ("matrix palette" is an old hardware feature for making bone matrices available to the vertex shader).  Basically you'd attach each model to a different bone and set each bone to the transform needed for that object.

However, this raises a problem where the object has to know which bone it should be attached to.  This would be done by adding a new vertex component for the bone index.  But this means you need a vertex buffer with multiple copies of the model, each with the bone index set to a different value in all its vertices.  Therefore you are paying a lot of video memory overhead by replicating the model several times.

Nowadays we would do all of this with instancing, which solves that problem; but I don't think hardware instancing existed in 2003 or 2004 when this talk was given.

Comment: You said: "Basically you'd attach each model to a different bone and set each bone to the transform needed for that object.
However, this raises a problem where the object has to know which bone it should be attached to." Could you expand upon it? We are using a palette animation library written by dastle and I am slowly learning how it works. I know that we are sending a huge (up to 56 elements) float4x4 array into a shader for each ModelMesh. The array represents the current frame's animation pose. The only way I see how it can be instanced is by putting more float4x4-s what am I missing?

Comment: In an instancing system, you have two vertex buffers: the "inner" one, which has the actual vertices for the model (just one copy of it), and the "outer" one, which has one vertex per instance and would contain the matrices for all bones (or a compressed representation thereof, as in the 2-float4 case here).

Comment: Ok I saw the instancing sample and was familliar with double-buffer hardware instancing system. I also thought about using it for my matrix palette skinning, but I ended up thinking it is infeasible as you can only have so many channels per vertex (my tests led me to the number 16 per name "TEXCOORD", "COLOR",...). I need 56x4 channels for that to work. With compression I will need 56x2 channels. So I will need 7 names for that. So if I reduce the number of bones supported it becomes feasible. Is this how it was supposed to work?

Comment: on the [D3D Semantics page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx) in the Vertex Shader inputs I counted 6 names (COLOR, TEXCOORD, BINORMAL, NORMAL, POSITION, TANGENT) that I can use, am I correct or do I have other channels available?

Comment: @cubrman Hmmm, you're right, there aren't enough vertex attributes to hold very many bones. I guess the way to do it is to either put the bones in an array of vertex shader constants, or in a float texture, and have an instance attribute store the offset to that instance's bones.  Unfortunately D3D9 only allows 256 constants, so a float texture might be what you need.  In D3D11 many more constants are possible, or structured buffers could be used.

Comment: Yes storing all the keyframes of every single animation for every bone in a texture is one way of instancing skined animations. Textures are prepared by the content processors, so things are working really fast. Then  you do a VFetch in the vertex shader and get all the variables you need. But this approach will most likely not work for me, because such animation system implies having only flat animations with rough transitions and no blending. The animation system by dastle that we use allows to do wonders, but it has its price. I guess I am cornered here :). Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @cubrman You can do whatever animation processing (eval keyframes, transitions/blending, etc.) you want on the CPU, and just put the final bone poses for that frame in the texture.  It would be updated every frame, not a static texture.

Comment: Wow, I haven't heard of that, how can it be done fast? I mean how do you build a texture on a cpu and put it into the GPU every frame? Could you share a link?

Comment: @cubrman It works the same way as a dynamic vertex buffer.  Namely, you create it with dynamic usage and pool, and then you can lock it using the discard flag and write to it each frame.

Comment: Ok but how do you set it as a texture in XNA? By a simple effect.Parameter["Texture"].SetValue(DynVertBuff) call? The compiler can do the type cast? Maybe your solution is c++ only?

Comment: @cubrman It's not a vertex buffer; it's a dynamic texture.  It's a regular texture object, but you create it with dynamic usage and pool, and use `LockRect` with the discard flag to update it.